# Admin_User_Session User_ID NULL

Tags: magento2, product, database

1,400 products were deleted fro my PROD Magento 2.2.1 community store.

Looking at the **admin_user_session** table there is an entry at the time I suspect the mass deletion was executed.

Is there an explanation for this?

[image]